# Is it possible to login to Linux/AWS instance using ssh key in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to login to Linux/AWS instance using ssh key in Jmeter?

We have to login to Linux system which has (login to the machines which are created using a public/private key) by using Jmeter and perform few actions.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can accomplished this using SSH Command sampler.

1. Download plugin manager https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/ and place the jar in your jmeter/lib/ext folder.
2. Open Jmeter >> Options >> Plugin Manager >>Install SSH Protocol Support
3. Restart Jmeter and add thread group, SSH command sampler and View result tree listener to your test plan
4. Enter the command you want to execute under command section and check the result in the listener.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @bsd007. It worked perfectly, able to ssh and run command successfully.